# Getting error while trying to use twitter 1.1 search

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, twitter, twitter-api-v1

I'm trying to get tweets using twitter's standard search API, this was working fine three weeks ago and now I'm using twitter-api-client 1.3.7 and getting this:

```
{
   "statusCode": 403,
   "data": "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product\",\"code\":453}]}\n"
}
```

this is my piece of code from my twitter controller:

```
Controller('Twitter')
@ApiTags('Twitter')
export class TwitterController {
  private twitterClient: TwitterClient;

  constructor(private readonly twitterService: TwitterService) {
    this.twitterClient = new TwitterClient({
      apiKey: process.env.API_KEY_TWITTER,
      apiSecret: process.env.API_KEY_SECRET_TWITTER,
      accessToken: process.env.ACESSO_TOKEN_TWITTER,
      accessTokenSecret: process.env.ACESSO_TOKEN_SECRET_TWITTER,
    });
  }

  @Get('/tweets/:tweet')
  @ApiOperation({
    summary:
      'Json',
  })
  async getTwitter(@Param('tweet') param_t: string) {
    try {
      const data = await this.twitterClient.tweets.search({
        q: '#' + param_t + '-filter:retweets',
        lang: 'en',
        count: 100,
      });
```

First, I was getting an authentication error and found out that my API key, bearer, and secret had disappeared from my developer account. After retrieving them again, I'm receiving this error.